# Wireshark can't capture raw socket only when protocol is TCP

Tags: sockets, tcp, python-3.6, raw-sockets

I'm trying to send a raw socket packet, writing my own IP header and TCP header, wireshark could capture the packets when the ip_protocol in the IP header is set to any number but 6 (which is TCP)

I,m working on Windows 10 and python 3.6.8.
My source IP and destination IP are all localhost.
I've also tried closing the firewall and it didn't help.
Any packet with IP protocol not 6 could be captured normally.
Wireshark cannot capture the packet only when I set ip_protocol = 6.

```
def carry_around_add(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return (c & 0xffff) + (c >> 16)

def CalculateChecksum(msg):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        temp = msg[i] << 8 + msg[i+1]
        s = carry_around_add(s, temp)
    return ~s & 0xffff
```

```
def GenerateIPHeader(ip_source, ip_dest):
    ip_ver = 4              # ipv4
    ip_ihl = 5              # Header Length = 5, no option
    ip_dscp = 0             # dscp (type of service)
    ip_total_len = 0        # left for kernel to fill
    ip_id = 0               # fragment
    ip_frag_offset = 0      # fragment
    ip_ttl = 255            # Time to live
    ip_protocol = 6         # TCP = 6
    ip_checksum = 0         # left for kernel to fill
    ip_saddr = socket.inet_aton(ip_source)
    ip_daddr = socket.inet_aton(ip_dest)
    ip_ver_ihl = (ip_ver << 4) + ip_ihl 
    ip_header = struct.pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ver_ihl, ip_dscp, ip_total_len, ip_id, ip_frag_offset, ip_ttl, ip_protocol, ip_checksum, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)
    return ip_header
```

```
def GenerateTCPHeader(SrcPort, DestPort, Checksum = 0, Flags = (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)):
    tcp_sport = SrcPort 
    tcp_dport = DestPort
    global SequenceNumber
    tcp_seq = SequenceNumber    
    tcp_ack_seq = 0     
    tcp_data_offset = 5     # No option

    # Flags
    tcp_flag_urg = Flags[0] 
    tcp_flag_ack = Flags[1]
    tcp_flag_psh = Flags[2]
    tcp_flag_rst = Flags[3]
    tcp_flag_syn = Flags[4]
    tcp_flag_fin = Flags[5]

    tcp_window_size = 3000  
    tcp_checksum = Checksum
    tcp_urgent_ptr = 0

    tcp_offset_reserv = (tcp_data_offset << 4)
    tcp_flags = tcp_flag_fin + (tcp_flag_syn << 1) + (tcp_flag_rst << 2) + (tcp_flag_psh <<3) + (tcp_flag_ack << 4) + (tcp_flag_urg << 5)

    # print(tcp_sport, tcp_dport, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_reserv, tcp_flags, tcp_window_size, tcp_checksum, tcp_urgent_ptr)
    tcp_header = struct.pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_sport, tcp_dport, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_reserv, tcp_flags, tcp_window_size, tcp_checksum, tcp_urgent_ptr)
    return tcp_header
```

```
def GeneratePacket(SrcAddr, SrcPort, DestAddr, DestPort, payload = ''):
    if len(payload) % 2 == 1:
        payload += " "
    IPHeader = GenerateIPHeader(SrcAddr, DestAddr)
    TCPHeader = GenerateTCPHeader(SrcPort, DestPort)
    PseudoIPHEader = GeneratePseudoIPHeader(SrcAddr, DestAddr, TCPHeader, payload)
    Checksum = b"".join([PseudoIPHEader, TCPHeader, payload.encode()])
    TCPChecksum = CalculateChecksum(Checksum)
    TCPHeader = GenerateTCPHeader(SrcPort, DestPort, TCPChecksum)
    TCPPacket = b"".join([TCPHeader, payload.encode()])
    packet = b"".join([IPHeader, TCPPacket])
    return packet
```

```
def GeneratePseudoIPHeader(ip_source, ip_dest, tcp_header, payload_data):
    psh_saddr = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip_source)
    psh_daddr = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip_dest)
    psh_reserved = 0
    psh_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
    psh_tcp_len = len(tcp_header) + len(payload_data)
    psh = struct.pack('!4s4sBBH', psh_saddr, psh_daddr, psh_reserved, psh_protocol, psh_tcp_len)
    return psh
```

```
def StartClient(SrcAddr, SrcPort, DestAddr, DestPort):
    try:
        Client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
    Client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)  #Set it to include the header
    Client.bind((SrcAddr, SrcPort))

    Packet = GeneratePacket(SrcAddr, SrcPort, DestAddr, DestPort, 'Hello!')

    print(Packet)
    Client.sendto(Packet, (DestAddr, DestPort))
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At a minimum, you should include the code for `GeneratePseudoIPHeader`, `CalculateChecksum`, and `GenerateTCPHeader` in your question since those are all critical to creating a valid TCP packet.

Comment: Do you see any malformed or unrecognized packet in wireshark? if so try to see if that is the packet you generated and share it with us.